# cannot import name '__version__' issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, openai-gym

i would like  to implement  Deep neural network+RL  in python, here is my code :

```
import  random
import gym
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import generic_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import  BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
env =gym.make("CartPole-v1",render_mode="human")
states =env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions =env.action_space.n

print(states,actions)
model =Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,states)))
model.add(Dense(units=24,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=24,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions,activation='linear'))
agent =DQNAgent(model=model,
                memory=SequentialMemory(limit=5000,window_length=1),
                policy=BoltzmannQPolicy(),
                nb_actions=actions,
                nb_steps_warmup=10,
                target_model_update=0.01
                )
agent.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01),metrics=['mse'])
agent.fit(env,nb_steps=20000,visualize=True,verbose=2)
# episodes =1000
# for episode in range(1,episodes+1):
#     state =env.reset()
#     done =False
#     score =0
#     while not done:
#         action =random.choice([0,1])
#         obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
#         done =truncated or terminated
#         score+=reward
#         env.render()
#     print(f"Episode {episode}, Score :{score}")
# env.close()
```

here is this issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\2024_Scientifi_Projects\cart_pole_Example.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rl.agents import DQNAgent
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Topics\venv\Lib\site-packages\rl\agents\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dqn import DQNAgent, NAFAgent, ContinuousDQNAgent
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Topics\venv\Lib\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 7, in <module>
    from rl.core import Agent
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Topics\venv\Lib\site-packages\rl\core.py", line 7, in <module>
    from rl.callbacks import (
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Topics\venv\Lib\site-packages\rl\callbacks.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import __version__ as KERAS_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'tensorflow.keras' (C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Topics\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py)
```

of course i can open any  python file and change some codes, but please tell me which version of tensorflow and gym are  completely compatible to each other?how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you import keras as a standalone library, it works:

[image]